# Нахождение рекурсивной суммы цифр цисла

Tags: python, алгоритм

```
def digital_root(n):
  num_arr = list(str(n))
  count = 0
  for i in num_arr:
    count += int(i)
  if len(str(count)) <= 1:
    return count
  else:
    digital_root(count)
```

Условие задачи:Цифровой корень — это рекурсивная сумма всех цифр числа.
Учитывая n, возьмите сумму цифр n. Если это значение имеет более одной цифры,
продолжайте уменьшать таким образом, пока не получите однозначное число.
Входные данные будут неотрицательным целым числом.

Вроде задачу решил правильно, но тесты не хочет проходить. Посмотрел решение других и их код также решает эту задачу как и мой. Видимо я что-то упустил. Помогите плиз)

Comment: нигде не забыли `return`?

Comment: Функция должна *вернуть* (`return`) значение, а не напечатать его.

Comment: Не в codewars return просто в pycharm оставил print так удобнее код просматривать

Comment: Приведите отформатированный код в том виде, как вы его посылаете на проверку. У задачи есть более быстрое решение, но пока лучше разобраться с этим

Comment: Я исправил. Все тоже самое просто return. В таком виде отправлял на проверку)

Comment: `num_arr = list(str(count))` внутри цикла ????

Comment: "*Зачем просто, если можно сложно?*", да? :) А не проще взять остаток от деления на 9 (и если получится ноль - то прибавить 9)?

Comment: Я проверял на числах и сравнивал два кода свой и других людей которые решали эту задачу результат выдавал один и тот же

Comment: Эта ветка кода вернёт `None` из функции: `else: digital_root(count)`

Comment: Решал первым решением которое пришло в голову

Comment: Когда отвечаете кому-то, лучше добавлять его имя, предваренное символом @... Ну так попробуйте другим методом :)

Comment: @Harry спасибо не знал

Comment: Ещё раз поясняю, если непонятно. Если какая-то ветка кода функции не имеет `return`, то из функции вернётся `None` после того, как код функции завершится, что у вас и происходит при рекурсивном вызове функции - управление рекурсивно уходит, потом возвращается, и функция доходит до конца - без `return`. В итоге возвращается `None`.

Comment: то есть надо писать return digital_root(count)

Comment: Ну да, все ветки кода функции должны иметь `return`, иначе в каком-то из случаев вернётся `None`.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то, эта задача решается за 25 символов:

```
def digital_root(n):
    return n % 9 or n and 9
```

Ну или так, рекурсией:

```
def digital_root(n):
    return n if n < 10 else digital_root(sum(map(int, str(n))))
```

Comment: Да я видел такие решения в codewars, но когда решал сам делал ,что первое приходило в голову

Comment: @ITexnik А вы перед тем как решать задачу, составляйте алгоритм, а потом уже решайте. Очень помогает.